# Define set of all twin primes without mention of prime number?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, definition

Do we have a definition of a set that is equivalent to the set of all twin primes such that the definition does not make mention of a prime number?
If not, would the discovery of such a definition be of any significance?

Comment: Such a discovery might suggest a new approach to some problems related to twin primes. Any new connection is useful information.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to find a set identical to the set of prime numbers without mentioning e.g. divisibility in there somewhere, or knowing infinitely many primes to begin with. Check out [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes), it might give you some interesting ideas.

Comment: This should be possible, but the representation would be rather abstract. A polynom with $26$ unknowns was constructed in a way, such that the positive values are exact the prime numbers. A similar polynomial should exists for the twin primes because, if I unerstood it right, every expression of a form like "for all a and b, there exists c,..." can be transformed into a polynomial, such that its integer roots are exact the tuples satisfying the expression.